# How automatically load all js controller files in Rails 7 with esbuild as JavaScript bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, esbuild

I'm trying to configure Rails 7 app to load all js Stimulus controllers automatically.

I use `esbuild` as JavaScript bundler.

If we're using Stimulus for Rails together with an import map, the integration will automatically load all controller files from `app/javascript/controllers`.

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/index.js

import { application } from "controllers/application"

import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

This `@hotwired/stimulus-loading` package comes from `importmap`

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
```

But it looks like `@hotwired/stimulus-loading` has not been published to NPM yet and is meant to be used only with `importmaps` in Rails.

When we're using Webpacker as JavaScript bundler we can use `@hotwired/stimulus-webpack-helpers` package to get the same form of autoloading behavior.

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import { definitionsFromContext } from "@hotwired/stimulus-webpack-helpers"

window.Stimulus = Application.start()
const context = require.context("./controllers", true, /\.js$/)
Stimulus.load(definitionsFromContext(context))
```

But when we're using `esbuild` JavaScript bundler on the official [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/installing#using-other-build-systems) page recommended to import each controller individually.

> Stimulus works with other build systems too, but without support for controller autoloading. Instead, you must explicitly load and register controller files with your application instance:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

import HelloController from "./controllers/hello_controller"
import ClipboardController from "./controllers/clipboard_controller"

window.Stimulus = Application.start()
Stimulus.register("hello", HelloController)
Stimulus.register("clipboard", ClipboardController)
```

**So my question is**:

Is it possible to configure Rails 7 with `esbuild` as JavaScript bundler to load all js Stimulus controller files from `app/javascript/controllers` automatically?

Answer (score 4):

**Manually running a task to include all stimulus controllers**

To include a new stimulus controller that you manually created in the `app/javascript/controllers/index.js` file, you can run:

```bash
rails stimulus:manifest:update
```

---

**Automatically including a newly created stimulus controller**

When you create a stimulus controller from the terminal with the generator, rails will automatically run the manifest:update command and so include your controller in js build.

```bash
rails generate stimulus controllerName
```

---

**Watching for live file changes to stimulus controllers**

To watch for live changes to your stimulus controllers, an additional watch process is needed. This additional watch process is appended to the `Procfile.dev` file after installing esbuild.

```bash
# Procfilde.dev

web: rails s -p 3000
css: yarn build:css --watch
js: yarn build --watch
```

The `yarn build --watch` command triggers the build command specified in the packacke.json file.

```json
{
  "name": "myapplication",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --outdir=app/assets/builds"
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. `rails stimulus:manifest:update` just goes through all controllers and does the same include it one by one in `app/javascript/controllers/index.js` so we have bunch of Stimulus js file imports. `rails generate stimulus HelloController` also does the same creates controller and adds these lines `import HelloController from "./hello_controller.js"
application.register("hello", HelloController)` to the `app/javascript/controllers/index.js`. So if we add one more we will have two imports and two registers. But I want to load all controllers at ones.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be done without adding additional esbuild config file. You can have a look at [this package](https://github.com/excid3/esbuild-rails).